# Why ajax request not sending?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have sample function for create event for any inputs of html form.

**Function code:**

```
function event(form, element) {
    var timer;
    $(element).keyup(function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        if ($(element).val()) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                form.submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url     : form.attr('action'),
                        type    : form.attr('method'),
                        data    : form.serialize(),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success : function (json)
                        {
                            console.log(json);
                        },
                        error: function(error)
                        {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    });
                });
                $(element).css("border-color","green");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(element).css("border-color", "#ccddea");
                }, 3000);
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var form = $('#form');

event(form, '#name');
event(form, '#lastname');
```

**HTML form code:**

```
<form action="http://localhost/app/form.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
    <div class="row bottom-mrg">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastname">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

**My** `form.php` **code:**

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'] ?? null;

if(isset($name)) {
    echo $name;
}
```

But after timeout **form not sending**. When I use only `form.submit()` it's work but with `ajax()` request not working. How to send ajax request in my situation?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I have to ask, where did you learn this syntax of attaching the event?

Comment: so whats up with the first var timer; clearTimeout(timer)? it is undefined?

Comment: Please add you form html code. Also: are you trying to submit the whole form on every keyup on a name or last name field? The jquery form.submit does the submit, then you get the results and pass to another function and try to send the form again via ajax. I wonder if the `form` variable is still available for use when the timeout finally calls that. You might be having scope issues.

Comment: @Jerdine Sabio, I have created this method for myself. You think it is not right?

Comment: @Pari Baker, In my function, I have not yet encountered an error about variables not found, so while I can not answer you anything. With timeout all working right!

Comment: Yes but if you console.log it will return undefined. Just asking it’s purpose not that it has any effect on the code working/not

Comment: @Pari Baker, Ok, where do you propose to change then?

Comment: @noderman,  I have add my html form code too.

Comment: @noderman, here in my javascript code when I use `form.submit()` all works but with reload page so I use ajax request for send data but it's not working.

Comment: put ur ajax call  out side `form.submit(function (e) {...` and remove `form.submit(function (e) {...`

Comment: Well I just tried it(on my phone using JSAnywhere) and I get an error because I don’t have the php page. So for me it works

Comment: Oh my bad that was the submit button. Sorry. I can’t answer right. Now I’ll take a look ASAP

Comment: But can you see if the interval is firing? Add a console.log and then do what @tphobe9312 said if it fires the console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and answer for my question! You can look, test and leave your opinion about the solution found.

**Javascript code:**

```
var form = $('#form');

function event(form, element) {
    var timer;            
    $(element).on('keyup', function () {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(function () {
        axios({
            method: form.attr('method'),
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });

        $(element).css("border-color","green");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(element).css("border-color", "#ccddea");
        }, 3000);
      }, 5000);
    });
    $(element).on('keydown', function () {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    });
}

event(form, "#name");
event(form, "#lastname");
```

I used **axios** but using **ajax** also possible.